Ubuntu keeps killing my processes and logging me out
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Desktop. I'm running a process that uses a large amount of swap disk. The process runs for around an hour and runs fine using 128 out of 128GB RAM and 256 GB out of 2 TB swap disk NVME. Then near the end when swap usage increases to around 300 GB the session ends and I'm logged out. I don't think it's a hardware issue as I changed out the RAM and NVME. AUto Screen lock and suspend are disabled. Swappiness at 60.
How can I stop getting the session terminated? Thanks!
ERRORS from log:
novato@novato-Super-Server:~$ sudo grep --text -ri 'killed process' /var/log/
/var/log/syslog:2024-11-28T23:54:31.369757-08:00 novato-Super-Server kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 6174 (python) total-vm:77951424kB, anon-rss:28399472kB, file-rss:116736kB, shmem-rss:2304kB, UID:1000 pgtables:70004kB oom_score_adj:200
/var/log/syslog:2024-11-28T23:57:43.092454-08:00 novato-Super-Server kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 8376 (python) total-vm:75541232kB, anon-rss:27676500kB, file-rss:119808kB, shmem-rss:9984kB, UID:1000 pgtables:70220kB oom_score_adj:200
/var/log/syslog:2024-11-29T00:01:16.232384-08:00 novato-Super-Server kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 10445 (python) total-vm:75645144kB, anon-rss:28301288kB, file-rss:114432kB, shmem-rss:2304kB, UID:1000 pgtables:69980kB oom_score_adj:200
/var/log/syslog:2024-11-29T00:29:10.753860-08:00 novato-Super-Server kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 24363 (swapoff) total-vm:18292kB, anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:768kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:60kB oom_score_adj:200
/var/log/syslog:2024-11-29T00:29:10.759830-08:00 novato-Super-Server kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 12190 (python) total-vm:213823008kB, anon-rss:22247060kB, file-rss:122112kB, shmem-rss:14592kB, UID:1000 pgtables:263252kB oom_score_adj:200
/var/log/journal/9c539c2437834f84bb1175357351d30c/user-1000.journal:9P

Already tried to turn off OOM killer.
Tried this already:
Kernel-level modifications:
# Modify sysctl settings
sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2
sudo sysctl -w vm.overcommit_ratio=100

# Make permanent by editing /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
# Add these lines:
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 100

Adjust OOM killer behavior for specific processes:
# Lower the OOM score for critical processes
# This makes them less likely to be killed
sudo echo -999 > /proc/$(pidof your_process)/oom_score_adj

Add kernel parameter at boot:
# Edit GRUB configuration
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

# Add to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:
oom_kill_disable=1


I am experiencing a similar behaviour on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a DELL XP13 with 15GB of RAM. After about an hour I suddenly get logged out, all running apps crash. When I check in syslog I see an out of memory: Killed process 4600 (gjs) in my case. The memory available for swapping became 0 at some point. This never happened on Ubuntu 20.04. It started after upgrading to 22.04 and it has not gone away in 24.04

Interesting. I switched back to Mint Linux. Never had this problem there even though the base is ubuntu 24.04

The pattern I observe consistently is of a memory leak. I have been observing it for a few weeks now and it is always the same process, gjs the JS process in GNOME using Wayland.
Message in syslog: XPS13 kernel: oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE, nodemask=(null), cpuset=user.slice, mems_allowed=0, global_oom, task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service, task=gjs, pid=40652, uid=1000
